# How can i get the pk from a cloned model instance in form_valid to use in get_success_url in an UpdateView?

Tags: python, django

```
class DomainRegistrationItemUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = DomainRegistrationItem
    form_class = DomainAddYearsForm
    template_name = "add_years.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DomainRegistrationItemUpdateView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # tld_ppy Top Level Domain Price Per Year
        context['tld_ppy'] = TLD.objects.get(
            name='.%s' % (self.kwargs['domain_name'].split('.')[1])).yearly_price
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return DomainRegistrationItem.objects.get(domain=self.kwargs['domain_name'], purchased=True)

    def get_success_url(self):
        split_dn = self.kwargs['domain_name'].split('.')
        namespace = split_dn[0]
        sld = split_dn[1]
        return reverse("domain_registraiton_item_detail", kwargs={
            "pk": self.kwargs['pk'],
            'namespace': namespace,
            'second_level_domain': sld})

    def form_valid(self, form):

        f = form.save(commit=False)

        working_dri = DomainRegistrationItem.objects.get(domain=self.kwargs['domain_name'])
        working_dri.pk = None
        working_dri.save()
        working_dri.purchased = False
        working_dri.years = f.years
        f.save()
        return super(DomainRegistrationItemUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The `working_dri` code is code that clones a DomainRegistrationItem under consideration by the view.

I want to get the pk from `working_dri` to usee in `get_success_url`. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UpdateView` stores the object it saves to `self.object`, as we can see in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123-L126):

> ```
>     def form_valid(self, form):
>         """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
>         self.object = form.save()
>         return super().form_valid(form)
> ```

so we can make use of:

```
class DomainRegistrationItemUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = DomainRegistrationItem
    form_class = DomainAddYearsForm
    template_name = "add_years.html"

    # …

    def get_success_url(self):
        split_dn = self.kwargs['domain_name'].split('.')
        namespace = split_dn[0]
        sld = split_dn[1]
        return reverse("domain_registraiton_item_detail", kwargs={
            "pk": self.object.pk,
            'namespace': namespace,
            'second_level_domain': sld})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.pk = None
        form.instance.purchased = False
        form.instance.years = f.years
        return super(DomainRegistrationItemUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```